# Solr partial update is not working

Tags: spring, solr

I'm trying to make Solr partial update is working with Spring Data.

```java
SolrTemplate solr; // autowired

public void updateEntry(final Entry entry) {
    PartialUpdate update = new PartialUpdate("id", entry.getId());
    update.add("foo_field", "hohoho");
    solr.saveBean(update);
    solr.commit();
}
```

However nothing happens with the document - the field "id" doesn't change. Deletion and creation are working. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing some partial update for my current project with spring data solr and it's working fine. Here's the code i have :

```
PartialUpdate partialUpdate = new PartialUpdate("id", "yourId");
partialUpdate.setValueOfField("fieldToUpdate", "value");
solrTemplate.saveBean(partialUpdate);
solrTemplate.commit();
```

Be sure to have the proper solrconfig for your core : (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates)

you will need to activate on your solrconfig.xml the updatelog and in your schema.xml you will need to defined the `_version_` field.